# Receive Nested xml Objects on spring boot

Tags: xml, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am new to Spring boot and spring rest concepts. I dont know how to receive nested xml request posted from browser.

Go through my basic codes. I am sending a post request from postman with nested xml objects on request body. I am unable to get my nested entity sent from browser in controller.

Here is my controller, entity and input xml.

**CrudRest Controller.java**

```
   @PostMapping(value ="/instructor/add",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE )
                public void insertInstructor(@RequestBody Instructor instructor) {
                    instructorDao.save(instructor);
                    System.out.println("inserted successfully");
                }
```

**Instructor.java**

```
            @Entity
            @Table(name="instructor")
            @XmlRootElement(name="Instructor")
            public class Instructor {

                @Id
                @Column(name="id")
                @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private int id;

                @Column(name="first_name")
                private String firstName;

                @Column(name="last_name")
                private String lastName;

                @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
                @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_detail_id")
                private InstructorDetail instructorDetail;

            }
```

**InstructorDetailDetail.java**

```
      @Entity
            @Table(name="instructor_detail")
            @XmlRootElement(name="instructorDetail")
            public class InstructorDetail {

                @Id
                @Column(name="id")
                @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private int id;

                @Column(name="hobby")
                private String hobby;

                @Column(name="channel")
                private String channel; 
            }
```

I am sending a post request with below as input using postman

```
  <Instructor>
    <id>2</id>
    <firstName>indu</firstName>
    <lastName>ramasamy</lastName>
    <InstructorDetail>
      <id>2</id>
      <hobby>reading</hobby>
      <channel>helly</channel>
    </InstructorDetail>
    </Instructor>
```

But in controller , I am receiving id,firstName, lastName alone in Instructor object. i.e) InstructorDetail(nested object) is received as null.

What I did wrong? can anyone help me out?